# Issues with 2D array peaks finder

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, 2d

I wrote this code with help of a tutorial, the code works fine but it does not output the answers I am supposed to get the answer that it gives me are (2,4)  and (3,3) which are 5530 and 5411 when I should be getting (2,1), (2,5), and (4,3) which are 5560, 5821, and 5831. the code should only output those 3 values

the code goes as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define columns 7
#define rows 6

int arr[rows][columns] = {
   { 5039,  5127,  5238,  5259,  5248,  5310,  5299 },
   { 5150,  5392,  5410,  5401,  5320,  5820,  5321 },
   { 5290,  5560,  5490,  5421,  5530,  5831,  5210 },
   { 5110,  5429,  5430,  5411,  5459,  5630,  5319 },
   { 4920,  5129,  4921,  5821,  4722,  4921,  5129 },
   { 5023,  5129,  4822,  4872,  4794,  4862,  4245 },
};

void find_peaks(int arr[][columns]);

int main() {
    
    find_peaks(arr);

    return 0;
}

void find_peaks(int arr[][columns]) {
    int curr = 0, peak_counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < columns - 1; j++) {
            curr = arr[i][j];
            for (int k = 0; k <= i + 1; k++) {
                for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++) {
                    if (arr[k][l] < curr)
                        peak_counter++;
                    if (arr[k][l] > curr)
                        curr = arr[i][j];
                }
            }

            if (peak_counter == 8)
                printf("peak at (%ld,%ld)\n", i, j);
            
            peak_counter = 0;
        }
}
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: The second `curr = arr[i][j];` looks useless because it assigns the same value again. Do you mean `curr = arr[k][l];`? I think you might have to do more things if you want to use k/l as the new peak coordinates. I suggest to run your program in a debugger step-by-step.

Comment: explain your peak finding logic a little more clearly please. are you looking for maximum value than neighbors or what is it?

Comment: Yes, basically a peak is defined to be a location at which the north, south, east, and west neighbors have lower values than the peak.

Comment: @GHGHGH: how about diagonals? Your algorithm attempts to test all 8 neighbours, which seem necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to find local maxima has some issues:

- the outer loop should start at `i = 1`
- the third loop should start at `k = i - 1`
- updating `curr` inside the inner loop seems unwarranted. You could break from the inner loop as soon as a test fails and `k != i` and `l != j`, but these extra tests might hurt performance instead of improving it. As coded, the inner loops should compile to efficient branchfree code.
- you should use `%d` for `int` arguments in `printf("peak at (%ld,%ld)\n", i, j);`
- it is idiomatic to use uppercase for the macros `columns` and `rows`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLUMNS 7
#define ROWS 6

int array[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {
    { 5039,  5127,  5238,  5259,  5248,  5310,  5299 },
    { 5150,  5392,  5410,  5401,  5320,  5820,  5321 },
    { 5290,  5560,  5490,  5421,  5530,  5831,  5210 },
    { 5110,  5429,  5430,  5411,  5459,  5630,  5319 },
    { 4920,  5129,  4921,  5821,  4722,  4921,  5129 },
    { 5023,  5129,  4822,  4872,  4794,  4862,  4245 },
};

void find_peaks(int arr[][COLUMNS]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < ROWS - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < COLUMNS - 1; j++) {
            int peak_counter = 0;
            int curr = arr[i][j];
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++) {
                for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++) {
                    if (arr[k][l] < curr)
                        peak_counter++;
                }
            }
            if (peak_counter == 8)
                printf("peak at (%d,%d): %d\n", i, j, curr);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    find_peaks(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
peak at (2,1): 5560
peak at (2,5): 5831
peak at (4,3): 5821
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation at the beginning, it really helps when someone shows you the errors that were made.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would solve the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define columns 7
#define rows 6

int arr[rows][columns] = {
   { 5039,  5127,  5238,  5259,  5248,  5310,  5299 },
   { 5150,  5392,  5410,  5401,  5320,  5820,  5321 },
   { 5290,  5560,  5490,  5421,  5530,  5831,  5210 },
   { 5110,  5429,  5430,  5411,  5459,  5630,  5319 },
   { 4920,  5129,  4921,  5821,  4722,  4921,  5129 },
   { 5023,  5129,  4822,  4872,  4794,  4862,  4245 },
};

void find_peaks(int arr[][columns]);

int main() {
    
    find_peaks(arr);

    return 0;
}

void find_peaks(int arr[][columns]) {
    int curr = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < columns - 1; j++) {
            curr = arr[i][j];
            //left, right, down, up, upper_left, upper_right, lower_left, lower_right
            if (arr[i][j-1] < curr && arr[i][j+1] < curr && arr[i-1][j] < curr && arr[i+1][j] < curr && arr[i-1][j-1] < curr && arr[i-1][j+1] < curr && arr[i+1][j-1] < curr && arr[i+1][j+1] < curr) {

                printf("peak at (%d,%d)\n", i, j);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how your algorithm is intended to work, so I just wrote my own.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLUMNS 7
#define ROWS 6

int arr[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {
   { 5039,  5127,  5238,  5259,  5248,  5310,  5299 },
   { 5150,  5392,  5410,  5401,  5320,  5820,  5321 },
   { 5290,  5560,  5490,  5421,  5530,  5831,  5210 },
   { 5110,  5429,  5430,  5411,  5459,  5630,  5319 },
   { 4920,  5129,  4921,  5821,  4722,  4921,  5129 },
   { 5023,  5129,  4822,  4872,  4794,  4862,  4245 },
};

void find_peaks() {

  int get (int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= ROWS) return -1;
    if (y < 0 || y >= COLUMNS) return -1;
    return arr[y][x];
  };

  for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
      int t = arr[y][x];
      if (t <= get(x + 1, y)) continue;
      if (t <= get(x - 1, y)) continue;
      if (t <= get(x, y + 1)) continue;
      if (t <= get(x, y - 1)) continue;
      if (t <= get(x + 1, y + 1)) continue;
      if (t <= get(x - 1, y + 1)) continue;
      if (t <= get(x + 1, y - 1)) continue;
      if (t <= get(x - 1, y - 1)) continue;
      printf("Peak of %d at (%d, %d)\n", t, x, y);
    };
  };
};

int main() {
  find_peaks();
  return 0;
};
```

If you don't actually care to find peaks on the edge of the array then you don't need the `get()` wrapper to check that you're not exceeding the array bounds, but instead you can just make the loops go from 1 to limit-1 instead.  You can also delete the second set of four `if () continue` statements if you don't care about the diagonals, but given what you indicate the correct answers are, it appears that you do.